# Inno Setup - Parameter "ValueData" is not a valid value

Tags: inno-setup, prtg

I'm trying to compile an installation package for a networking monitoring utility called PRTG. I am basically doing this:

http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/60635-how-can-i-silently-install-a-remote-probe-in-my-network

except, I'm trying to automate it.

Everything works except for one Registry key:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Wow6432Node\Paessler\PRTG Network Monitor\Probe"; 
    ValueType: dword; ValueName: "Password"; ValueData: "8b9a69b9"
```

I've tried Hexadecimal and Decimal and neither worked.  Oddly, when I remove the above characters and replace it with *any other value* the installer will compile.

Help me Obi-One Kenobi!

Comment: Don't use `Wow6432Node` in the Subkey.  Use `Root: HKLM32` instead if you want to guarantee using the 32-bit registry.  (Even that is not necessary if you haven't enabled 64-bit mode, as Inno defaults to using the 32-bit registry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using hexadecimal notation, you were missing the `$` prefix char. So this would work:

```
ValueData: "$8b9a69b9"
```

This is described in the [`[Registry]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) section documentation for the `ValueData` parameter as:

> If the data type is dword or qword, this can be a decimal integer
>   (e.g. "123"), a hexadecimal integer (e.g. "$7B"), or a constant which
>   resolves to an integer.

Comment: I read that thing a thousand times - I just assumed the $ was a character apart of a dword in the example.

Comment: That `$` prefix actually comes from Pascal language on which is based Delphi, language in which is Inno Setup written (and which is responsible for parsing script section values). So the notation itself has some [`historical background`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Using_0.E2.80.939_and_A.E2.80.93F).